# Maximal principles

Tags: set-theory, solution-verification, alternative-proof, axiom-of-choice

> *Prove that Hausdorff's Maximal Principle is equivalent to the following: If $(A,\preceq)$ is a partially ordered set and $B$ is a chain of $A$, then $A$ has a maximal chain $\mathfrak{C}$ such that $B\subseteq\mathfrak{C}$*.

Proof: Let $(A,\preceq)$ and $B$ is a chain of $A$.  let's consider $\mathfrak{F}$ as the collecction of all the chains of $A$ that continent to $B$ ordered by inclusion, by *Hausdorff's Maximal principle*, $\mathfrak{F}$, has a maximal chain $\mathfrak{C}$; let $K=\bigcup \mathfrak{C}$, and it will be shown that $K$ is a maximal chain of $A$ that continent to $B$:

Let $x,y \in K$, then $x\in D$ and $y \in E$, for some $D,E\in \mathfrak{C} $, since $\mathfrak{C}$  is a chain, $D\subseteq E$, or $E\subseteq D$,  then $x,y\in D$ or $x,y\in E$, in both cases $x,y$ are comparable.

from the above it is concluded that $K$ is upper bound of $A$, and by *Zorn's Lemma*, $\mathfrak{F}$ has a maximal element. which is precisely $K$.

Hence $B\subseteq \mathfrak{C}$.

I would like to know if the proof is completely correct, I have doubts about the other equivalence, I would like to know if it is possible to receive a suggestion.

---

Comment: Can you perhaps come up with a title that describes the actual question? You have 150 characters, and using math symbols is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof uses Zorn's lemma incorrectly. In fact, you shouldn't be using Zorn's lemma at all. But in any case, to apply Zorn's lemma you need to show that *every* chain has an upper bound, and you've only showed that *one* chain has an upper bound.

Instead, you need to use the following fact:

> **Proposition.** Let $(P,\prec_P)$ be a partial order, and let $K\subseteq P$ be a maximal chain. If $p$ is an upper bound of $K$, then $p$ is a maximal element (and $p\in K$).

Then you move directly from verifying that $K$ is an upper bound of $\frak C$ to $K$ being a maximal element of $\frak F$.

---

Alternatively, use Zorn's lemma directly by showing that the union of a chain of chains in $A$ is itself a chain in $A$, and therefore by Zorn's lemma there exists a maximal element.

Comment: Hi, I think in the final part of the proof, I wrote that $K$ was a upper bounded of $A$, it's actually from $\mathfrak{C}$, I would like to know if in that case I can apply the Zorn's Lemma. thanks

Comment: Again, the point of using Zorn's lemma is to apply it to *all* chains. You started by using Hausdorff's Maximality Principle to pick a maximal chain. This is equivalent to saying "Using Zorn's lemma, there is a maximal element, so by the well-ordering theorem we can well-order all the maximal elements and use the Axiom of Choice to choose one". That's just now how you use these principles. No. What you wrote is fine, but instead of using Zorn's lemma, you need to argue that this upper bound you found, of that maximal chain, is a maximal element, directly. Not by using Zorn.

Comment: Thank you si much, I was complicating a Little, but I am already clear.